# Make checkstyle check javax path annotation

Tags: java, checkstyle

I am trying to create a checkstyle module with regex that checks if a javax.ws.rs.Path annotation starts with a slash or not.

In my checkstyle.xml file I have defined

```
<module name="Regex">
    <property name="format" value="/api" />
    <property name="message" value="Missing /" />
</module>
```

What I want it to check is if I have a resouce class as the following

```
@Path("/api/v1/persons")
public class PersonResource {
  ...
}
```

Then it shall pass the check without any problems, on the other hand if my class looks as follows

```
@Path("api/v1/persons")
public class PersonResource {
  ...
}
```

Note that the first `/` is missing then it should get an error/warning from my checkstyle.

Now is this possible to achieve with checkstyle or do I have to write my own [check](https://checkstyle.org/writingchecks.html).

And I cannot seem to find anything in [Annotations](https://checkstyle.org/config_annotation.html) that does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard Check to make what you need, but there are non standard Checks and http://sevntu-checkstyle.github.io/sevntu.checkstyle/apidocs/com/github/sevntu/checkstyle/checks/annotation/ForbidAnnotationElementValueCheck.html should be able to enforce proper values, you just need to craft proper regexp. Project page https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle . If you have problems with usage of custom Checks, it is possible to move this Check to standard library, but this will require your help to make it.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at it when I get the time :), see if I can construct something proper working check.